# Whats wrong with this code in three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am new to html and three.js.. the following code will not display.... can someone please assist? I think it may be a problem with canvas, but I'm not sure.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test.html</title>
        <style>

            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvas.width/canvas.height, 1, 30);

            var scene.add(new THREE.DirectionLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

            var model = new THREE.Object3D();

            var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 2, 10, 16);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} )
            var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            model.add(cylinder);
            scene.add(model);

        </script>

    enter code here
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You never declare a variable called `canvas`, so the expression `canvas.width` is going to cause a runtime error. You have no `<canvas>` element in your HTML.

Comment: Please take a look at the [three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs). The very first item is a basic sample: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene Compare this against what you have, and you'll find you missed several important steps.